# Disable Spring Dependency Injection in Glassfish

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, glassfish

How can I disable Dependency Injection in Glassfish so that it doesn't conflict with spring?

Is it possible to configure in glassfish-web.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. It is possible to inject an EntityManager in Spring without resorting to @PersistenceContext. There is a Spring factorybean to create a shared EntityManager. Given an Entity Manager Factory:

```
<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="myJpaFacade" class="com.example.MyJpaFacade">
    <property name="entityManager" ref="entityManager" />
</bean>
```

Now I can remove the @PersistenceContext annotation from MyJpaFacade so that Glassfish doesn't try to lookup and inject an entity manager into the entityManager property.

Comment: Another benefit is that JRebel is now much better at reinjecting a new EntityManager if the entity beans or persistence.xml has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Spring can use different annotations that GF wont' understand. Without some examples of your code it's hard to go further.

There isn't anything that's going to turn DI off... it's part of the container, so you'll need to use annotations it doesn't care about.

Comment: The problem is @PersistenceContext, which is injected from Spring. I haven't been able to find a non JEE, Spring alternative.

Comment: Just use the full package name like  @javax.persistence.PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;

Comment: I fail to see the difference between @PersistenceContext EntityManager em; (with an import in the top of the java file) and @javax.persistence.PersistenceContext private EntityManager em; Both are injected from Glassfish, which fails, and my spring configuration file, which would succeed if Glassfish went out of the way.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Spring. Based on your problem I made the assumption that Spring also has a PersistenceContext annotation that's conflicting with the javax one. If that's not the case then why do you care if GF is injecting it?

Comment: Yes, they are both using jpa @PersistenceContext, Glassfish fails because no connectionpool has been set up in Glassfish. Spring can inject an entitymanager based on its configuration.